# Notification buttons don't work for just one user

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

I have a notification for controlling media. I used to use my own custom views but now I've switched to `MediaStyle`. This is used for playing media tens of thousands of times per day by a lot of users. I have one single user that has ever complained that the buttons on the notification don't work. I got logs from him and my `BroadCastReceiver` is never getting called when he presses the buttons. What is also strange is that when I didn't use `MediaStyle`, he had the same exact issue.

This is how I set the intents:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayingBroadcastReceiver.class);
        intent.setAction(action);
        PendingIntent pending PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), id, intent, 0);
        notifBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.icon, context.getString(R.string.label), pending);
```

What am I doing wrong? I've tested this on tons of phones and never had the issue, I have also never heard from a single other user with this issue after millions of uses of this notification.

This issue is on a Samsung Galaxy S6.

Edit: Got more info from the user today. I have an pending intent that opens an activity, it is set on `setContentIntent`. That one apparently works. The only difference is that that one uses `PendingIntent.getActivity()` vs the other that uses `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` and of course the class the intent calls is different.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is perhaps his phone has a custom ROM?  If that's so maybe getApplicationContext() is returning an invalid context which in turn may not be locating the intents and targets to deliver to?

Comment: He does have a custom rom, but I'm guessing the application context is working since I use that all over the place and the notification does show, just not the pressing of the buttons.

Comment: The thing that I'm not certain about is that perhaps the Context is changing. Depends on the memory management of the ROM. So maybe the ApplicationContext no longer exists when the Pending Intent fires.  I'm guessing since I don't have the logs or can debug to be honest but that is my gut reaction.

Comment: Got more info from the user today. I have an pending intent that opens an activity, it is set on `setContentIntent`. That one apparently works. The only difference is that that one uses `PendingIntent.getActivity()` vs the other that uses `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`.

Comment: Solved, turns out the user had disabled my broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the user had manually disabled the `BroadcastReceiver` of my app. After months of complaints it is finally fixed.